# Atribuição de valores diferente do normal

Tags: python, python-3.x, operadores

```
def testes(x, y):
    while y:
        x, y = y, x % y

    return x
```

Eu não entendi essa parte do código, o que acontece com o 'x' e o 'y' do lado esquerdo do sinal de igual e o que o 'y' faz do lado direito. Essa linha 3 é confusa para mim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está vendo a capacidade de Python de fazer múltipla atribuição.

Você conhece a atribuição simples e ela é fácil de entender. à esquerda do sinal de atribuição `=` há o nome de uma variável e do lado direito, depois desse operador, há uma expressão que gerará um valor que será atribuído para a variável.

Neste caso tem mais de uma variável do lado esquerdo, então deve ter de uma forma ou de outra a geração de mais de um valor. Pode ser que uma única expressão gere valores diferentes ou podem ser várias expressões.

No caso específico tem duas variáveis e duas expressões. Então a primeira expressão será o valor atribuído para a primeira variável, enquanto a segunda é atribuída para a segunda variável.

Esse é um exemplo curioso porque ele faz ainda uma coisa que chamamos de *swap*. Ele troca valores ao mesmo tempo. Então quando executar o valor de `y` passa ser atribuído para `x` e o valor de `y` passa ser um cálculo do resto de `x` dividido por `y`. Obviamente o valor de `y` usado na primeira atribuição é o valor antes de mudar logo em seguida. E o valor de `x` usado na segunda expressão é o valor `x` anterior, não o que fez a atribuição anterior.

Isso pode ser escrito assim também:

```
def testes(x, y):
    while y:
        temp = x
        x = y
        y = temp % y
    return x
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9XLpia). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gxgqdntd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/Swap.py).

Comment: Interessante. Então, todos os valores da parte da direita são calculados antes de qualquer atribuição.

Comment: Exatamente. Python preza por códigos curtos.

Comment: Outro detalhe, é que `while y:` significa que enquanto `y` não for igual a zero o laço não vai parar de ser executado. Neste caso, a cada iteração a variável `y` recebe um valor menor até zerar.

Comment: def testes(x, y):
    while y:
        x, y = y, x % y

    return x

# neste caso na linha 3. x = y e y = x % y então x vai mostrar o resultado de x % y 
é isso?

Comment: @TiadoDev Vai ter um processo aí, mas no final acabará sendo o resultado do penúltimo resto. Agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.

Answer (score 0):

Essa linha poderia ser quebrada em duas, dessa maneira:

```
def testes(x, y):
    while y:
        x = y
        y = x % y

    return x
```

Dessa maneira, enquanto `y` for diferente de 0 (condição para o `while` parar), o valor de `x` vai ser alterado para `y` e o valor de `y` vai ser igual ao resto da divisão de `x` por `y`.

Comment: neste caso, o x que está sendo dividido por y terá o mesmo valor de  y? ficando y % y ?

Comment: @TiadoDev No caso, foi mais uma representação para demonstrar como estava sendo atribuído aquela linha. Mas se fosse feita a atribuição de forma separada, seria necessário uma variável auxiliar. Ao fazer tudo em uma unica linha, o valor de x e y (depois do sinal de `=`) ainda são os valores "originais".